# Backpropagation gradients diffrence between my NN and Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I wrote a neural network from scratch and it works but I have a question there. My NN uses full batch and the gradients are therefore calculated with the entire matrix. Because I was interested, I checked how tensorflow.keras does it and they calculate the gradients for each individual row of my input and not the entire matrix directly. Is my approach wrong or what are the differences?